# Ce n'est pas terrible, ce n'est pas mal

Tags: expressions

Pourquoi les français disent-ils souvent « ce n'est pas terrible » ? Est-ce que cela veut dire « c'est terrible » ? Quand ils disent « ce n'est pas terrible », personnellement, je comprends « ah, c'est normal ». Mais non, ça veut en fait dire « c'est vraiment terrible » !

Et ils disent aussi « c'est pas mal », c'est-à-dire « c'est super ». Cette logique est bizarre et difficile à comprendre pour les étrangers comme nous. Peut-on m'expliquer, s'il vous plaît ?

Comment: Comme vous êtes étranger, j'ai corrigé les fautes de la question pour que vous voyiez vos erreurs. N'hésitez pas à jeter un oeil au suivi de modifications.

Comment: Merci Mr. Random :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'expression est en effet étrange. Suivant le contexte, on peut avoir plusieurs explications.

### C'est pas mal

Suivant l'intonation, cela peut être compris comme "bien" ou comme "bof/moyen"

1. « J'ai vu le film, il est pas mal » veut dire qu'on a aimé le film
2. « -T'as vu le film ? -Mouai, il est pas mal, sans plus... » veut dire que le film était standard, sans grande surprise par exemple...

### C'est terrible

Peut également avoir 2 sens complétement opposé.

1. Avec une intonation positive (langage familier), "terrible" veut dire "super/génial" : « Ce concert était terrible ! ».
2. Avec une intonation négative (langage courant), "terrible" est très négatif: « J'ai une terrible nouvelle à vous annoncer »

L'expression "C'est pas terrible" faisant plutôt partit du langage courant, il y a des chances pour que ce soit le sens négatif de "terrible" qui soit utilisé.

### Nuance entre « C'est pas mal » et « C'est pas terrible »

Si on prend l'échelle de grandeur suivante :

1/5: Très mauvais (terrible)
2/5: Mauvais (mal)
3/5: Moyen (correct)
4/5: Bon (bien)
5/5: Très bon (super/génial/excellent)

L'expression "C'est pas mal" veut dire « un peu mieux que "mal" » (donc moyen ou bon), et l'expression "C'est pas terrible" veut dire « un peu mieux que "Très mauvais" », donc mauvais ou moyen...

Cela expliquerait la différence.

N.B: Ce raisonnement ne se base sur aucune source, uniquement sur l'usage.

Comment: Pure and simple irony probably explains one of my favorite examples of strange uses of the negative, but perfect timing and intonation are still required to make it work as well as Les Inconnus did in their bar sketch: "Avec tout ça on est pas dans la merde!"

Comment: @PapaPoule - The "strange uses of negative" are ironical figure of styles (named *antiphrase*) like "c'est malin" (*Well done*) that means that you did some thing wrong. "Avec tout ça on est pas dans la merde!" means to be in deep shit. I think that "c'est pas terrible" is not an *antiphrase* and that, in this expression, terrible refers to something awsome, impressive. Then, "Cet hotel n''est pas terrible" can be translated as "this hotel is nothing special".